# how can I add groups under an active/inactive child?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have successfully been able to send data to the firebase server however I am having trouble getting the data to send to the appropriate data subset I have created. When I send data made in the html form, It sends organized by ID number. I need it to be sent as a child to the 'groups' category in firebase.

here is a Plnkr with the server and $add working. Any suggestions I would really appreciate!

http://plnkr.co/edit/LZ24sRoSJjuCHQnEGzQz?p=linter

```
   .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'groupsService', function( $scope, groupsService,  $firebase ) {

$scope.newGroup = {
  name: '',
  status: ''
};

$scope.addGroup = function(newGroup) {

  groupsService.addGroup(newGroup);

  $scope.newGroup = {
    name: '',
    status: ''
  };

};
$scope.updateGroup = function (id) {
  groupsService.updateGroup(id);
};

$scope.removeGroup = function(id) {
  groupsService.removeGroup(id);
};
}])

.factory('groupsService', ['$firebase', 'FIREBASE_URI',
  function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URI) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI);

    var groups = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

    var getGroups = function(){
     return groups;
    };

   var addGroup = function (newGroup) {
     console.log(newGroup)
     groups.$add(newGroup);
   };

  var updateGroup = function (id){
    groups.$save(id);
  };

  var removeGroup = function (id) {
    groups.$remove(id);
  };

return {
  getGroups: getGroups,
  addGroup: addGroup,
  updateGroup: updateGroup,
  removeGroup: removeGroup,
 }

 }]);
```

Thanks for responding! What I am trying to do is add dummy data (name and status) to the groups category like this:

```
  {
   Groups:[
        "-JcFXid1A2G8EM7A_kwc" : {
           "name" : "hi",
           "status": "inactive"

      },

       "-JcFZP5FNtL4Yj6nja_7" : {
           "name" : "hi"
           "status": "inactive"
      },
       "-JcFtGoZL7J-CCIjTYcL" : {
           "name" : "dfgdfg",
           "status": "inactive"
      }
   ]
}
```

would it make more sense to have them organized by active or inactive? I am afraid to nest too far in firebase...

like

```
 {
   Groups:[
          "Active":[

           "-JcFXid1A2G8EM7A_kwc" : {
            "name" : "hi",

           }
          ],
          "Inactive":[

            "-JcFZP5FNtL4Yj6nja_7" : {
              "name" : "hi"          
      },

            "-JcFtGoZL7J-CCIjTYcL" : {
               "name" : "dfgdfg"

      }
    ]
  ]
 }
```

Comment: Hi Lizajean. Can you limit yourself to a single question? For example: "why aren't my groups showing?" or "how can I add groups under an active/inactive child?". Right now there are too many questions/problems here to answer in one go.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have simplified it.

Comment: Which data format is best for you, depends on what you want to do with the data. If you want to show a list somewhere of all groups with a column that displays their active/inactive status, then I would keep the format you currently have. Your fear of building deep hierarchies is justified and in this case I would leave the list of groups as a list of groups. But as said: it depends on the use-cases you want to handle, which only you can know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This isn't an answer to your question yet, because I first need to understand what you're trying to accomplish (and I can't fit this amount of information in a comment).**

In your view you have a form that binds to the group's name and status:

```
<form role="form" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-submit="addGroup(newGroup)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="groupName">Group Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="groupName" ng-model="newGroup.name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="groupStatus">Group Status</label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="newGroup.status">
      <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
      <option value="active">Active</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In your GroupsService you essentially add a group like this:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI);
var groups = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
groups.$add(newGroup);
```

Which adds the group to the collection at that URL.

Which leads to this data structure:

```
{
    "-JcFXid1A2G8EM7A_kwc" : {
        "name" : "hi",
        "status" : "inactive"
    },
    "-JcFZP5FNtL4Yj6nja_7" : {
        "name" : "hi",
        "status" : "active"
    },
    "-JcFtGoZL7J-CCIjTYcL" : {
        "name" : "dfgdfg",
        "status" : "active"
    }
}
```

But if I understand you correctly you to want the data to be stored like this:

```
{
    "inactive": [
        "-JcFXid1A2G8EM7A_kwc" : {
            "name" : "hi"
        }
    ],
    "active": [
        "-JcFZP5FNtL4Yj6nja_7" : {
            "name" : "hi"
        },
        "-JcFtGoZL7J-CCIjTYcL" : {
            "name" : "dfgdfg",
        }
    ]
}
```

1. Is this indeed what you're looking to do?
2. Are you ever going to display active and inactive groups combined in a list? This is important to know, since it is quite easy to filter a list in Angular, but I wouldn't know how to merge two lists.

Comment: I just updated my question. Thanks for responding! The active and inactive lists would most likely be displayed separately, if that helps.

Comment: Hey Lizajean, you might want to actually copy a bit more from my write-up. I tried to turn it into a little MCVE for that purpose. ;-)